# Select all same tags in exactly same location of a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

i'm facing the following problem and really need a solution for it:
I'm coding an extension that will change some attributes of an exactly 'a' tag which is inspect from outside link. And this extension run in all web page. Maybe it'll be more clearly in my under explanation.

Assume that the HTML bare-bones of a random website is sth like:

```
<body>
.....
<p> paragraph </p>
<div> a div tag </div>

<div id="sth">
  <div id="someId">
    <a>
      <img>
    </a>
    <label> 
      ...
    </label>
  </div>
  (more 5 'div' tags like this)
</div>
...
</body>
```

The problem is, i'm now in the location of that 'a' tag (Inspect from an outside link) so don't know where exactly is the parent element, also don't know the id of the parent element (which is the "div id='sth'" tag, and cause my extension run in all webpage) and wanna select all the 'a' tags like that in the same location of other "div id='someId'" tags (cause all of those "div id='someId'" tags are almost the same) and do sth like, change all the value of 'href' attributes to "*https://www.google.com/*".

If you find out the solution, please give me a hand. Thanks.

Comment: Without your actual code it's unclear what you mean by "i'm now in the location of that 'a' tag" so I guess you could use `el.closest('div[id]')` to get the div.

Comment: thanks for the answer and sorry for my bad explanation ^^ Honestly i think that only me can understand what i think -.-

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explanation of selecting parent element with example 
Element property returns the parent element of the specified element.

```
("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
( "p" ).parent( ".selected" ).css( "background", "yellow" );
```

```css
    a
    /* visited link */
    a:visited {
      color: green;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    a:hover {
      color: hotpink;
    }

    /* selected link */
    a:active {
      color: blue;
    }
```

```html
    <div><p>Hello</p></div>
    <div class="selected"><p>Hello Again</p></div>




    <body>
    .....
    <p> paragraph </p>
    <div> <a>www.google.com </a></div>

    <div id="sth">
      <div id="someId">
        <a href="www.google.com">
          <img src="img.png">
        </a>
        <label> 
          ...
        </label>
      </div>
      (more 5 'div' tags like this)
    </div>
    ...
    </body> 

<!-- end snippet -->

Javascript
```